# How do you run development-signed build in in-app purchase?

Tags: iphone, sandbox, in-app

In Apple's "In-App Purchase Programming Guide" I read following advice when it comes to testing in-app purchase using Sandbox test.

> Create a test user account in iTunes Connect.
>
> On a development iOS device, sign out of the App Store in Settings.
>
> Then build and run your app from Xcode.
>
> Use your app to make an in-app purchase. When prompted to sign in to
>   the App Store, use your test account.
>
> Note that the text “[Environment: Sandbox]” appears as part of the
>   prompt, indicating that you’re connected to the test environment. If
>   the text “[Environment: Sandbox]” doesn’t appear, you’re using the
>   production environment. Make sure you’re running a development-signed
>   build of your app. Production-signed builds use the production
>   environment.

My question is, How do I make sure that I am running a development-signed build of my app? Where exactly is that done, and what steps must I perform?

Answer (score 0):

Project Setting -- >Build Settings
then search "code signing"
then you could see the options to select